# How to remove only one specific data which appears multiple time in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage

I have items that I add to the cart by storing them in a localStorage with their ID.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.set-cart-info', function () {
    // We retrieve the product id which is stored in the url
    var url_id = window.location.search;
    var id = url_id.split('?id=').pop();
    // We retrieve the data from the localStorage
    var cartItems = localStorage.getItem('teddy_id');
    // If there is no data, we create an array
    cartItems = cartItems ? cartItems.split(',') : [];
    // Add the new data to the array
    cartItems.push(id);
    // We save the data in the localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('teddy_id', cartItems.toString());
});
```

In the console.log I get this :

```html
localStorage.getItem('teddy_id')

"5beaacd41c9d440000a57d97,5beaabe91c9d440000a57d96,5beaabe91c9d440000a57d96,5beaaa8f1c9d440000a57d95,5beaabe91c9d440000a57d96,5beaaa8f1c9d440000a57d95,5beaabe91c9d440000a57d96,5beaacd41c9d440000a57d97,5beaaa8f1c9d440000a57d95,5beaaa8f1c9d440000a57d95,5beaaa8f1c9d440000a57d95,5beaabe91c9d440000a57d96,5beaacd41c9d440000a57d97,5beaacd41c9d440000a57d97,5beaacd41c9d440000a57d97,5beaacd41c9d440000a57d97,5beaacd41c9d440000a57d97,5beaaa8f1c9d440000a57d95"
```

Then, I added the possibility of adding or removing a quantity of a product by retrieving the product ID and adding it to the localStorage, my problem is as follows: when I retrieve the ID to fetch it in the localStorage, it deletes all items with this ID, I would like it to remove only one.

Here is the code that allows to add a quantity, and the one that should be modified so that it also removes only one :

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add_qty', function () {
    // We retrieve the product id which is stored in the class
    var split_class = this.className.split(' ');
    var this_id = split_class[1];
    var cartItems = localStorage.getItem('teddy_id');
    cartItems = cartItems ? cartItems.split(',') : [];
    cartItems.push(this_id);
    localStorage.setItem('teddy_id', cartItems.toString());
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove_qty', function () {
    // We retrieve the product id which is stored in the class
    var split_class = this.className.split(' ');
    var this_id = split_class[1];
    var cartItems = localStorage.getItem('teddy_id');
    cartItems = cartItems ? cartItems.split(',') : [];

    // This is the part that retrieve the product by his ID and delete all product with this specific ID
    var newStorage = cartItems.filter(function(r) { return r !== this_id});
    localStorage.setItem('teddy_id', newStorage.toString());
});
```

```html
$('.product_in_cart' + '.' + ID._id).append('
<td class="product_in_cart_changeqty">
<button onClick="window.location.reload()" class="add_qty ' + ID._id + '">+</button>
<button onClick="window.location.reload()" class="remove_qty ' + ID._id + '">-</button>
</td>');
```

Thanks in advance for your time and help :)

Comment: You should `JSON.stringify(newStorage)` rather than `.toString()` it, so you can easily `JSON.parse()` it back into an object/array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember that array methods are your friend. One way you could do this is combine the use of `array.prototype.find()` with `array.prototype.splice()` as follows:

```js
cartItems.find( ( item, i ) => {
   if ( item == this_id ) {
      cartItems.splice( i, 1 );
      return true;
   }
   return false;
} );
```

This way, it’s only removing the first matching item that it comes upon.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with the use of local storage once you store ID array its gets stored in the form of an array while retrieving the data you need to fetch the string json parse it and then run the required operation. Check this [eg](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-y8kh5t).

Comment: it looks like the code is already handling that. Though it’s not using JSON.parse(), there’s a ternary operator that splits the string into an array of the data exists.

Comment: why use all that ?? handling it's not required if a pre-written method can easily do that for you/. also, your issue is with handling an array inside local storage which I explained well in my eg.

Comment: I’m not saying that using a ternary operator is preferred. I’m just saying that that’s not is what’s causing the issue. I do however agree that it would be better to use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify

Comment: I too got that from eg. just I am trying to simply say with my eg is no need to find it in the array from UI you are already getting the id just need to pass in the splice. yours too can be a solution just saying thing my way!